Material Instance not updating in real time
I have InstancedStaticMesh, and i want to change color of only one instance. To do this i use SetCustomDataValue node in my BP to pass float value to material instance. But when i call node, nothing happens in game; however if i eject by pressing F8 and select instance, it changes it color, but goes back to default after i select anything else. UE version 5.3
I assume this is some problem with Unreal caching or not updating material instance for some reason, but can't figure how to fix it. SetCustomDataValue node has MarkRenderStateDirty input, but it doesn't change anything. sending float from BP receiving it in material

There are no caching issues in the editor regarding materials. Are you using a MaterialInstanceDynamic?

@MaxPlay i was not, but i've tried using it - the problem still occurs

What exactly are you passing in as custom data?

@MaxPlay just a float, 0 for default color, 1 for changed. In material it should change R value of param. I added screenshots to post so you can see it now.

Finally solved it, i spawned two meshes at the same location, so if you are experiencing something like this - make sure you have only one mesh component and/or you instances are not overlapping.
